# Rails: Architecture for an app framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a Rails app we have a requirement, where in end users, should be able to make
applications for our application. Similar to facebook app. Is there
any known architecture for this, or is there any open source example
which does this. Please suggest.

Regards,

Pankaj

Comment: he can't spend time on it since he is busy building another Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be a bit more clear about the sort of interaction you're expecting from the end-user apps with your app.

- If you only need to frame their apps inside yours and pass params to them, then a simple iframe should do the trick
- If you need the apps to have more JS functionality (make calls/pass params to your JS) then they either need to be hosted on a sub-domain of your site (e.g. x.example.com) to avoid cross-site scripting errors, or you need to provide them with a JS API (like Facebook).
- If you need the apps to make calls to your rails app (server-side) then you need to create an API which the apps can call.